# Converting Curl API Call to Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell 5

Tags: powershell, curl, powershell-5.0

I have done a bunch of searches, but nothing so far as helped me solve this. Any help is appreciated.

I am trying to convert a `curl` command to `Invoke-WebRequest`, but for some reason I am not getting a response back. I have tried:

```
$headers = @{
    outh_a    = "WEBREQ";
    oauth_key = "key";
    etc...
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Body "{}" -Headers $headers -Verbose
```

The `curl` command looks like this:

```
.\curl.exe -x POST -d "{}" -H "oauth_a: WEBREQ" -H "oauth_key:key" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "oauth_sm:HMAC-SHA2" -H "oauth_t:timestamp"-H "oauth_s:key+signature=" "https://example.com/services/api/request?t=data&a=data2&n=404&i=0"
```

The command works perfectly and returns the data. I am using PowerShell as we want to parse through the data once received. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The `curl` command will fail if I submit it without `-d "{}"`, so that part is required. The server I guess is expecting to receive a specific amount of data.

I am not sure what is going on to prevent a response. I have tried `curl` from the same machine I am doing the PowerShell script on and it works. I even used SoapUI to make the same call and it works there too.

**Edit**:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = 
[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 
[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls, 
[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$Domain = "https://example.com/services/api/request?t=oauth_auth_token&a=appid&n=404&i=0"

# OAUTH Authorization Request Header

$Header = @{
    o_nonce = 'TEST'
    o_con_key = 'key'
    o_sig_meth = 'type'
    o_timestamp = 'timestamp'
    o_sig = 'signature'
    o_ver = '1.0'
    o_realm = 'http://example.com/services'
} 

$Body = @{}

$API_Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Headers $Header -Uri $Domain -Body $Body -Verbose -TimeoutSec 20
```

Comment: Try `-Body @{}`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ansgar. However, that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

@MikeW I'd have to look at your PS code in more detail, could you post the entire API call minus the sensitive information (api key etc...)?

Also, on a side note, sometimes just passing the parameters on the URI works just as well. Have you tried passing the parameters through the URI? You can see the following example of an API call I'm making using just the URI:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ("$EndpointURL/Tickets/$TicketID/?username=$ServiceAccount&apiKey=$APIKey");
```

Comment: Thank you Peter for your reply. I tried using:

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Body @{} -Headers $headers -Verbose

No luck on that. Server simply doesn't reply, like I am not passing something correctly.

Comment: @MikeW I've updated my answer. Please see if you can provide additional information or try the URI parameter passing method.

Comment: I have edited my original answer to include the Power Shell code. It is very basic, just the variables for the headers & Invoke-RestMethod call.

Comment: @MikeW Have you tried requesting data without the headers? Do you get any error back? I'm trying to determine if you're getting any response at all or not.